# Deploy maven web application to Tomcat from Eclipse

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, maven, deployment

I created new maven web-application with Eclipse (File->New->Other... Maven Project)
I have installed Tomcat server.
When I tryed run application, internal eclipse browser show 404 error.
I found out that my application was not builded and deployed to the Tomcat.
My pom.xml has only one record regarding deploying:

```
<build> 
<finalName>MyArtifactId</finalName> 
</build>
```

what I need do more to run this application?
Thank you.
PS I did not got such errors when I used ant, but I had more items in xml for deploying with ant.

Comment: please refer this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeC7XQho-O0 :)

Answer (score 1):

What is your goal for Maven?  To have it automatically deploy your project to the tomcat server and/or build a war file?

To build a simple war file, I would use the maven-archetype-webapp to create a reference project that can build a war file and then you can manually copy the war file to the tomcat webapp folder.